# Connect two PCs over GSM modems without GPRS

Tags: networking, mobile-devices, dialup, gsm

Is there a way to connect two PCs via two GSM modems without using GPRS ?
Something like the good old hyperterminal over dialup or any way to make data calls from cell to cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could obviously use a GSM datacall, if you set up both sides of the link accordingly. The setup is quite straightforward, but there are [walkthroughs for this on the net](http://www.testech-elect.com/enfora/tutorial_gsm_datacall.htm) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Without a carrier to provision the devices, I doubt that you would be able to do this for a few reasons.

1) You would need to be a licensed operator on the bands that your modems would use.
2) The radios in the modems aren't designed to talk directly to each other.  The modems would expect to an APN setup to talk to to configure services.
3) Your question itself is a bit flawed as the data itself is carried over a GPRS link even when a carrier is involved. GSM only handles voice and SMS.

If you are trying to configure short haul point to point communications, you might have better luck using 802.11a/b/g/n in ad-hoc mode instead.  The communications link would be free and you could use telnet to communicate between the two given the proper software.  There are also unlicensed radio bands that allow for packet data as well.  In the US, MURS comes to mind for this.  There are others as well, but you'd need to check with local authorities to find out what is available.

Admittedly, I don't know that much technical detail about your modems.  Maybe someone with a more technical background can chime in and either agree or disagree.